# How does one handle this case when finding the interval of convergence on a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have the problem:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}*x^{2n}}{n+1}$$

I used the ratio test and got this this point and don’t know how to move forward:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{n+1}{n+2}*\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2n}}\right|$$

Please help

Thank you

Comment: How do you get your ratio.

Comment: With $f(n)=(-1)^nx^{2n}/(n+1)$ we have $|f(n+1)/f(n)|=x^2(n+1)/(n+2).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet exactly my point not what the OP has.

Comment: @Chinny84. Yes. I was just adding some detail.

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test is not a summation of the ratio of the absolute value of consecutive terms of the series as in the OP.  Rather, it is the limit of the ratio of the absolute value consecutive terms.

Applying the ratio test reveals

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| =\lim_{n\to \infty}x^2\frac {n+1}{n+2}=x^2<1$$

whenver $|x|<1$.

Note that the test tells us nothing about the convergence or lack thereof for $x=\pm1$ as the ratio test is inconclusive when $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=1$.

But we can test for convergence directly.  For $x=\pm 1$, Leibniz's Test guarantees convergence.

Comment: I'll just add that it tells us nothing about convergence at 1 or -1 because those points make the ratio test inconclusive. +1

Answer (score 1):

You require, by the root test
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup \left|\frac{x^2}{(n+1)^{1/n}}\right|<1\implies x^2<1\implies |x|<1
$$

and on the boundary we have something bounded by the alternating harmonic series, which converges, yielding a radius of 
$$
|x|\leq 1
$$